# Swift: WKWebView: How can I detect that the user has been redirected to a "Sign In to Enable Wifi Access" page?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, reachability

There are certain wifi hotspots, such as hotel lobbies and airports, where you technically have an internet connection, and Reachability will return True, however, you are redirected to their Sign-In screen, where you need to first provide login credentials in order for the WiFi to work. (WiFi provider’s Authentication page or "Captive Portal page")

How can you go about detecting such a use case in a generic way?

I could obviously detect a page redirect from my original page, and treat that as a sign-in prompt. However, what if my actual server call also uses redirects under-the-hood, and ends me up at a different page than the one I requested (this is common).

So it doesn't seem that I can just check for a redirect or compare my requested URL against the resolved URL.

Is there a special category or handling mechanism in `WKWebView` for web requests to detect the "WiFi authentication required" type of page?  (a generic solution that would work for any internet provider).

Comment: what's your aim ? Detect internet connection or exactly the sign in page ?

Comment: I want to present a custom instructional message in the application that hints to the user that they need to open the web browser, and sign in to the WiFi provider's page.  But I do not want to open this said page in my own application due to strict security requirements.  Currently I have no choice but to show a blank page.

Comment: The first clue would be to put breakpoint on delegate call and check the url which comes in.

Comment: hmm... checking wifi versus internet connection can be a work around to hint the user

Comment: You need to do what iOS does; retrieve a specific page and look for a known response. If you get a different response then something is up. I.e. when iOS connects to a new wifi it retrieves `http://captive.apple.com`; if that page isn't the text "Success" then the hotspot connection process is initiated.